# Why doesnt it get data from SQLite database?

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to connect to a database located in my project directory and get data from it, but is give `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` error.

Here is my code:

```
public static Connection ConnectDB(){
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database01s.sqlite");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected");

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT id FROM DAN" );

        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println( rs.getInt("id") );
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It does connect successfully, but it gives error when it reaches this line: `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT id FROM dan" );`

And this is a picture of my database to to see if I am entering the right table and info:[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You don't appear to set `stmt` to anything other than `null`. An NPE seems inevitable.

Comment: You should also consider using an ORM like Hibernate, which makes life much easier.

Comment: @Synturas Depends, really; when just starting out is good to know the basics. Otherwise when Hibernate explodes there's no context for debugging.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, but i think it's also good to know what's possible, and it would be bad, to never have heard about it.

Comment: @Synturas Thanks for mentioning it. I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a null pointer exception because stmt is equal to null, and you are calling executeQuery() on it. You can't call methods on a null object.

Comment: Instance methods, anyway; you can call static method on a null reference.

Comment: @DaveNewton, you can't call a static method on a null reference.

Comment: Actually you can. Maybe try it first.

Comment: So how can I initialize it? I mean what should I put instead of null ?

Comment: Maybe something like statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM DAN");

Comment: @satnam E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/12665474/438992 and a ton of others here on SO.

Comment: Thanks but didnt work. I got same error but this time for added line.

Comment: Then that means that your "conn" variable is null Dan, correct?

Comment: Dave Newton, trust me I know how statics work. I was calling you out on your wording. You can't call a static method on a "null reference". You CAN call a static method without a reference.  For example, you CANNOT do "foo.bar()" when foo is null.  You can however say "Foo.bar()"

Comment: @satnam yes `conn` is null too.

Comment: @Sanam Call me out all you want, but you're completely wrong, and there are a ton of references here on SO even if you're too lazy to just try it or check the JLS. That's why I provided you the links.

Comment: @DaveNewton, go write this program and see if it works for you:
Foo foo = null;
foo.staticMethod();

Comment: @Dan, aren't you setting conn like this:  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database01s.sqlite");

Comment: @DaveNewton, just read it again. And tested it. You were right I was wrong. I did not know you could do that lol

Comment: @satnam with your help I could fix it. I moved `Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();` afte the line : `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database01s.sqlite");` So `conn` isnt null anymore, and it did work. Thanks btw