# Accessing static method through an object instance

Tags: java, static-methods

I have learnt that if we wish to call static method of another class then you have to write class name while calling static method. In below program, I created object of the Employee class inside Employee_Impl class and using that object, I was still able to access the `count` method. Why is it allowing me to use `count` method through an object if `static` methods are accessed using only class name? Does that mean static methods can be accessed using objects as well as class name, both?

`Employee.java`

```
public class Employee{
    static int counter = 0;
    static int count(){
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }
}
```

`Employee_Impl.java`

```
class Employee_Impl
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Employee obj = new Employee();
        System.out.println(obj.count());
        System.out.println(Employee.count());
        System.out.println(obj.count());        
    }
}
```

`output`

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't calling a static method by way of an instance an error for the Java compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co)

Answer (score 9):

Compiler automatically substitutes this call by call by class name of your **variable** (**not** of it's **value**!). Note, even if your object would be null, [it will work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8042129/3084258), no `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

You are allowed to do this because you made an instance of `Employee` to access the method through.

The point of static methods is to allow access to "utility methods" that can be invoked without the overhead of instantiating a new object. Furthermore, these methods can be shared by any instance of the class `Employee` and can mutate shared static variables or attributes. For example, pretend the shared prefix of all `Employee` objects was maintained as a static attribute:

```
public class Employee {
    private static String EMPLOYEE_IDENTIFIER_PREFIX = "Acme Corporation Employee Number:"

    public static void setEmployeeIdentifierPrefix(String prefix){
         Employee.EMPLOYEE_IDENTIFIER_PREFIX = prefix;
    }
}
```

If `AcmeCorporation` was purchased by `MultinationalCorporation` the prefix can be updated for all `Employee` objects by using the `setEmployeeIdentifierPrefixMethod` on the class like so:

```
Employee.setEmployeeIdentifierPrefix("Multinational Corporation Employee Number:");
```

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are always executes from class...not from objects...
here.., even though you are calling `count()` method on object `obj.count()`
it will executes from `Employee` class only...
first it will identify the class of object then from that object type it will execute the `count()` method.