# Function::identity doesn't work in Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream, collectors, collect

I am trying to turn a `List<String>` into a `Map<T, String>`, with the value of the map being an element contained within the previous `List<String>`, and the key being some attribute of that `String` (for example, the length of the `String`, in which case, `T` would actually be an `Integer`).

I first attempted to do it this way. This is an implementation of the example I mentioned above. I want the length of the `String` to be the key, and the `String` itself to be the value. I wanted to use the `Function::identity` function to clearly specify that the value is the `String` itself.

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SOQ_ME_20220522_fail
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      final List<String> list = List.of("apple", "banana", "coconut");
      
      var result = 
         list.stream()
            .collect(
               Collectors.toMap(
                  each -> each.length(),
                  Function::identity
               )
            )
         ;

      System.out.println(result);
   
   }
   
}
```

However, when I tried to compile it, I got the following compilation error.

```
SOQ_ME_20220522_fail.java:15: error: no suitable method found for toMap((each)->ea[...]gth(),Function::identity)
               Collectors.toMap(
                         ^
    method Collectors.<T#1,K#1,U#1>toMap(Function<? super T#1,? extends K#1>,Function<? super T#1,? extends U#1>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1,K#1,U#1
        (argument mismatch; unexpected static method <T#2>identity() found in unbound lookup))
    method Collectors.<T#3,K#2,U#2>toMap(Function<? super T#3,? extends K#2>,Function<? super T#3,? extends U#2>,BinaryOperator<U#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#3,K#2,U#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Collectors.<T#4,K#3,U#3,M>toMap(Function<? super T#4,? extends K#3>,Function<? super T#4,? extends U#3>,BinaryOperator<U#3>,Supplier<M>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#4,K#3,U#3,M
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,K#1,U#1,T#2,T#3,K#2,U#2,T#4,K#3,U#3,M are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1,K#1,U#1>toMap(Function<? super T#1,? extends K#1>,Function<? super T#1,? extends U#1>)
    K#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1,K#1,U#1>toMap(Function<? super T#1,? extends K#1>,Function<? super T#1,? extends U#1>)
    U#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1,K#1,U#1>toMap(Function<? super T#1,? extends K#1>,Function<? super T#1,? extends U#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>identity()
    T#3 extends Object declared in method <T#3,K#2,U#2>toMap(Function<? super T#3,? extends K#2>,Function<? super T#3,? extends U#2>,BinaryOperator<U#2>)
    K#2 extends Object declared in method <T#3,K#2,U#2>toMap(Function<? super T#3,? extends K#2>,Function<? super T#3,? extends U#2>,BinaryOperator<U#2>)
    U#2 extends Object declared in method <T#3,K#2,U#2>toMap(Function<? super T#3,? extends K#2>,Function<? super T#3,? extends U#2>,BinaryOperator<U#2>)
    T#4 extends Object declared in method <T#4,K#3,U#3,M>toMap(Function<? super T#4,? extends K#3>,Function<? super T#4,? extends U#3>,BinaryOperator<U#3>,Supplier<M>)
    K#3 extends Object declared in method <T#4,K#3,U#3,M>toMap(Function<? super T#4,? extends K#3>,Function<? super T#4,? extends U#3>,BinaryOperator<U#3>,Supplier<M>)
    U#3 extends Object declared in method <T#4,K#3,U#3,M>toMap(Function<? super T#4,? extends K#3>,Function<? super T#4,? extends U#3>,BinaryOperator<U#3>,Supplier<M>)
    M extends Map<K#3,U#3> declared in method <T#4,K#3,U#3,M>toMap(Function<? super T#4,? extends K#3>,Function<? super T#4,? extends U#3>,BinaryOperator<U#3>,Supplier<M>)
1 error
```

Now, this is very easy to workaround - I just need to sacrifice some readability by replacing `Function::identity` with `(t -> t)`. Doing this, the class compiles and runs just fine.

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SOQ_ME_20220522_success
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      final List<String> list = List.of("apple", "banana", "coconut");
      
      var result = 
         list.stream()
            .collect(
               Collectors.toMap(
                  each -> each.length(),
                  t -> t
               )
            )
         ;
         
      System.out.println(result);
   
   }
   
}
```

```
{5=apple, 6=banana, 7=coconut}
```

My question is this - why am I unable to use `Function::identity` to be able to fetch the data I need? Looking at the documentation for [`Function::identity`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#identity()), we can see that this static interface method is supposed to return a `Function<T, T>` that returns the object it receives. And if we go to the source code itself, we can see that it creates the [exact same lambda](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/function/Function.java#L97) that I did. So I am confused why the first attempt failed. Obviously, I am able to get past it easily, but I still want to know why the first attempt failed.

Comment: You want `Function.identity()`, not `Function::identity`.

Comment: Also, if there might be multiple strings with the same length then you either want to provide a merge function or use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)).

Comment: @Slaw I see what you mean. That definitely worked. Please turn your comment into an answer and I will give it a checkmark.

Comment: @Slaw Yes, that was an arbitrary example that was poorly thought up. Truthfully, I'm using this pattern style to glean metrics from a `Collection<T>` of data. Ran into this bug, and then I created this runnable example that captured the point in it's smallest form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `Function::identity` with `Function.identity()`.

The former, which is a method reference, would only work if you had a stream of `Function` objects and you wanted to call the `identity` method on each of them. The latter is simply a static method call which returns a `Function` that you pass as the value mapper argument.

Two notes:

1. The `each -> each.length()` lambda expression can be written as `String::length` (a method reference). Though you of course can keep it as a lambda expression if you want to.
2. If multiple elements can map to the same key (e.g., in your example, if multiple strings can have the same length), then consider either providing a [merge function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) or using [`Collectors#groupingBy(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Are static methods incapable of using the `::` syntax? Please let me know if that should be a separate question.

Comment: No. It's possible for a static method can be used as the target of a method reference. Say you had a static method `static void display(Foo f)` and you had a `List<Foo>`. You could do `fooList.forEach(TheClass::display)`. The method reference `TheClass::display` is the same as the lambda expression `(Foo f) -> TheClass.display(f)`.

Comment: In other words, you need to make sure a method reference can be applied for the given number of arguments and the types (including return type, if any) involved.

Comment: That makes sense. It sounds like the reason why my attempt failed is because `Function.identity()` already returns a function. So, to do `Function::identity` is to essentially say, *return a function that returns a `Function`*

Comment: Yeah, essentially. `Function::identity` would be the same as doing `(Function<T, R> func) -> func.identity()`. Basically a `Function<Function<T, R>, Function<T, T>>` (I think; the generics might be off as I haven't tested it). If the `func.identity()` is confusing to you, that's because it's confusing; you can [call static methods on an instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039657/accessing-static-method-through-an-object-instance), but [you should not do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884004/is-calling-static-methods-via-an-object-bad-form-why).

Comment: That clarified everything. Thank you for the detailed explanation. I understand the concept much better now.